# How to configure mimproxy certificates on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, proxy, certificates

How are the steps to configure the certificates of [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on Arch Linux?

When opening mitm.it in the browser, it shows the following steps for Linux, but they are Ubuntu/Debian specific:

```
mv mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mitmproxy.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I found a recipe for Arch Linux [here](https://gist.github.com/franciscocpg/a4f52afcc00d472a9d7c407db16a92ee):

```
After installing mitmproxy run it (just type mitmproxy) in a terminal session and quit.
This will create the necessaries certificates files at ~/.mitmproxy.

Extract the certificate to .crt format:
openssl x509 -in ~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca.pem -inform PEM -out ca.crt

Trust the certificate into CA:
sudo trust anchor ca.crt

Run the mitmproxy again

Open another terminal session and set the proxy:

export http_proxy='http://localhost:8080'
export https_proxy='http://localhost:8080'

Run a curl to an https site and it should work:
curl https://www.google.com
```

Before I run it, I wanted to check whether the approach is sound. I am also curious how to revert the changes. Is there a way to "untrust" the mitmproxy certificate once you no longer need it? Or is it safe to leave it installed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach is fine. In fact, you don't even need to convert the cert, just use `~/.mitmproxy/mitmproxy-ca-cert.cer` directly.

To untrust the cert, refer to the instructions under `man trust`:

```
ANCHOR
       Store or remove trust anchors.

           $ trust anchor /path/to/certificate.crt
           $ trust anchor --remove /path/to/certificate.crt
           $ trust anchor --remove "pkcs11:id=%AA%BB%CC%DD%EE;type=cert"

       Store or remove trust anchors in the trust policy store. These are usually root certificate authorities.

       Specify either the --store or --remove operations. If no operation is specified then --store is assumed.
```